# Semantic classes in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I apologize that this is probably a basic question, I tried searching other topics for an answer, but I'm still unsure.

I submitted a project where I needed to build a basic portfolio page using Bootstrap. I lost points for the following line of code:

```
<div class="container">
```

> You need to add semantic tags. A semantic element clearly describes its meaning to both the browser and the developer. You can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

I understand why we should be using semantic tags however if I change the class from container to anything else it will adjust all the margins on the page. It was my understanding that Bootstrap recognized "container" and automatically applied Bootstrap properties to its children.

Am I doing anything wrong? Or am I just supposed to make a CSS rule that will apply margins to whatever I change container to?

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated, errors like this will become compounded with further projects!

Comment: <div class="container"> is pretty standard for bootstrap. It should be a div. It is not a form, image, table, etc, it is a div. I'm not sure why you would have gotten points off for that specific line. I suppose you could change it to a section tag as <section class="container"> but I've never seen it done this way.

Comment: I agree with @brino but i think your tutor is probably aiming more at elements containing actual content. It would be good to see a sample of your markup to get a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Your teacher is either being pedantic or trying to teach you a lesson - they might have intended you to use HTML5 elements like <section> or <article> to break up your HTML.

Comment: My guess is whoever is grading you had no clue what they are talking about, and probably doesn't even work in this field.

Comment: Depends where it is. Context is important. Perhaps `<main>` or `<section>` would have been better, but without seeing the structure of the markup, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: you likely lost marks because that div serves no purpose other than styling. the `div` is largely unnecessary as you can add `class="container"` (or another class with your required margins) to an HTML element that contains some actual content (a `p` or `section` tag perhaps)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are confusing tags and classes slightly: `<div>` is a tag - more specifically an element - and `.container` is a class. You can place the `.container` class on any element you want.

```
<p class="container"></p>
```

There are no definitive rules for class names, and as such they are not really a part of semantics, or SEO. A general suggestion is that they simply describe the element, not the styles.

Wherever you submitted your project most likely wanted to see a `<section>`, `<article>`, `<aside>` or some other HTML5 purely semantic element, which may or may not be proper semantics - kind of depends on what's inside it, and where it lies relative to the rest of the markup.

Generally speaking, the `.container` class is usually applied to generic elements in Bootstrap, and `<div>` is usually perfectly reasonable.

Another thing to consider, [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/) is a historically low quality source for web information, and usually a good indication that whomever is linking to it doesn't know very much about the web. I'd advise you to just start reading the tutorials and articles over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web), you'll learn a lot faster.

Comment: I find this to be another good resource for info about semantic elements: http://html5doctor.com/article-archive/